# how to create a server from my pc accessible to any other pc on the intranet

Tags: python, mysql, flask, server

I am new to this field. I have made a simple website using Python Flask. Also created an reverse geocoding api using MySQL database and flask.

All these are hosted in my own pc i.e. local host. Now I want to make an interactive website (form). But I don't want to host it on remotely accessible server like Amazon AWS. 
  My assumption is, since I am working in an environment whre my pc is connected to an intranet where so many others are also connected, I will host the server on my pc and others will access the website from it.

Since I lack theoretical knowledge about server and staffs I am unable to do so. Any suggestion for reading material is appreciated.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import mysql.connector

my_db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="XXXX",
    database="cat")

my_cursor = my_db.cursor()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/rev_geocode/lat=<float:lat>,long=<float:long>', methods['GET'])


def rev_geocode(lat,long):

    my_cursor.execute("SELECT address FROM rev_geocode WHERE lat = {} AND lon = {};".format(lat, long))
    data = my_cursor.fetchall()

    return jsonify({"address":str(data[0][0])})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

# http://127.00.1:5000/rev_geocode/lat=<float:lat>,long=<float:long>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `ifconfig` coomand on Linux terminal to determine your machine's IP address. Replace 127.0.0.1 with the IP address in URL. Other users in the intranet can now access your app.

Comment: what about the port number?

Comment: Keep it in the URL, same as before.

Comment: It worked, thank you. Can you provide any link for proper documentation.

Comment: @Epsi95: documentation for what?

Comment: I think Flask Docs will suffice. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I requested `http://your_ip:5000/rev_geocode/lat=31'OR DROP TABLE rev_geocode; — priv,long=12` - what would happen?

Comment: "Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again". Nice trying SQL injection lol!

Comment: @Epsi95 ah, flask cleans up your inputs in the decorator, I didn't know or notice that part. Carry on!

Answer (score 0):

You can give local host as your own IP address . Then run your program using that IP, similarly you can use the same IP to run on machines connected in the same LAN.

change your allowed hosts=[ip address]

then run on it .

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy, change `app.run(debug=True)` to `app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')`. Then others can find your form by going to the ip of your machine.

[Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) - under 'Externally Visible Server'